# Aggregating dates by month in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, yahoo

I've got a table with the following columns:

- Date
- Open
- High
- Low
- Close
- Volume
- Adj Close

Its basically a yahoo stock csv import.

What I want to do is to create a monthly view of the following daily prices but I am not sure how.

Id like the new view to have the following results:

- Dates, the last date of the month or just the month itself,
- Open, the first open of the month,
- High, the highest price for the month,
- Low, the lowest price for the month,
- Close, the last close of the month,
- Volume, the sum of all volumes,
- Adj Close, The last adj close for the month.

Is it possible to create a view like that in Postgres?

Comment: Take a look at postgresql window functions.

Comment: If you're looking for a more detailed answer, I suggest a more detailed question - `create table` and `insert` statements for sample data, and an illustration of the expected results. Otherwise, start here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html